# HTML5 video pausing in between

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

I need to run some business logic along with rendering video. The logic is mapped with the frames of the video. So, to play the video at the actual frame rate, I am using my custom logic as follows,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <video id="frame_img" class="frame_img" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"></video>
    <button id='play' class='play' title='play' accesskey="P">Play</button>
    <button id='pause' class='pause' title='pause' accesskey="P">Pause</button>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){               
            var play_handle;
            function playVideo()
            {
              play_handle = setInterval(function(){

                $(".frame_img")[0].currentTime = $(".frame_img")[0].currentTime + 0.040;
                console.log($(".frame_img")[0].currentTime);
              },40); 
            }

            function pauseVideo()
            {
              clearInterval(play_handle);
            }

            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
              $("#play").on('click',function(){
                // alert("I will Play the video");
                playVideo();
              });

              $("#pause").on('click',function(){
                // alert("I will Pause the video");
                pauseVideo();

              });
            });
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

What is happening here is, On clicking on Play, video starts playing but stops for a while in between and again starts playing. For my long video it stops several such times in between. I am not getting the reason for the the stops in video rendering. Please help me in identifying my mistake in the business logic.

Comment: my guess would be that your video isn't optimized for streaming and it's waiting for content to catch up

Comment: @Offbeatmammal https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4 video when played normally plays properly. Similar is the case with other videos